# Fast method of applying sine to a matrix

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I need to optimize this code.

```
# K             sparse node coupling matrix
# P             vector of net power production at each node
# alpha         vector of damping at each node
# n             number of dimensions
# theta         vector of phases
# omega         vector of angular velocities


    def d_omega(K,P,alpha):
        def layer1(n):
            def layer2(theta,omega):
                T = theta[:, None] - theta
                T = np.sin(T)
                A = K*T
                A = A.dot(np.ones(n))
                return - alpha*omega + P - A
            return layer2
        return layer1
```

I know a large portion of the computation time is used in the

```
T = np.sin(T)
```

line. Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: The performance of this depends on your installation of Numpy. So you have to check whether that installation is optimal for your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula). That way we can reduce the number of expensive function evaluations from `n^2` to `2n` (if we count complex functions double). What we are doing is expressing the sine of an outer difference as an outer product of complex exponentials. As multiplication is much cheaper than a sine this results in a good net speedup:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def pp():
    T = np.exp(1j*theta)
    T = np.outer(T,T.conj()).imag
    return T

def orig():
    T = theta[:, None] - theta
    T = np.sin(T)
    return T

rng = np.random.default_rng()

theta = rng.uniform(-np.pi,np.pi,1000)

print(np.allclose(orig(),pp()))
print(timeit(orig,number=10))
print(timeit(pp,number=10))
```

Sample run:

```
True                     #  results are the same
0.2818465740419924       #  original method
0.04591922601684928      #  Euler
```

Speedup (depends on number of elements of theta, here 1000) ~6x

Depending on the shape of `K` (scalar, 1D or 2D) we can optimize further:

```
def pp():
    T = np.exp(1j*theta)
    if K.ndim == 0:
        A = T*(T.sum().conj()*K)
    elif K.ndim == 1:
        A = T * (K@T.conj())
    else:
        A = T * (K@T.conj())
    return A.imag

def orig():
    T = theta[:, None] - theta
    T = np.sin(T)
    A = K*T
    A = A.dot(np.ones(1000))
    return A

rng = np.random.default_rng()

theta = rng.uniform(-np.pi,np.pi,1000)

for K in (rng.uniform(-10,10,shp) for shp in ((),(1000,),(1000,1000))):
    print(np.allclose(orig(),pp()))
    print(timeit(orig,number=10))
    print(timeit(pp,number=10))
```

Sample run:

```
True
0.493153132032603
0.0012746050488203764
True
0.49636399815790355
0.0012419759295880795
True
0.47554834792390466
0.05685037490911782
```

So with `K` scalar or a vector we get a ~350x speedup, while if `K` is a matrix it is only ~8x.

Comment: @yatu Just element by element. In the meantime OP now says `K` is indeed a matrix.

Comment: In Numpy, is there an easy way to exploit the fact that the `np.sin(T)` matrix is skew-symmetric?

Comment: @gboffi Doesn't my method count? ;-) I'm not aware of any direct support; there is (via blas) very limited support for symmetric matrices but as far as I konw that's it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I tried your first comment, but didn't see speed up in my code. I will make sure to try this most recent one soon.

Comment: That helped with the code. Can you explain the `A = T * (K@T.conj())` line please?

Comment: @DamienBeecroft One just needs to verify it gives the same result as your original code which is `\sum_j sin (\theta_i - theta_j) K_ij` The matrix-vector product ` `K@T.conj()` is `sum_j K_ij e^{-i \theta_j}` times T gives `sum_j K_ij e^{i \theta_i - theta_j}. Taking the imaginary part (assuming `K` is real) gives the sine.

Answer (score 0):

From the assignment

```
T0 = θ[:, None] - θ
```

we have that `T0[i,j] = θ[i]-θ[j]` and from

```
T1 = sin(T0)
```

we have `T1[i,j] = sin(θ[i]-θ[j])` but from simple trigonometry

```
T1[i,j] = sin(θ[i])*cos(θ[j]) - cos(θ[i])*sin(θ[j])
```

Recognizing that `sin(θ[i])*cos(θ[j])` is an element of the matrix that results from the outer product of `sin(θ)` and `cos(θ)` we can write a little program that I've checked interactively

```
In [42]: from numpy import allclose, arange, cos, sin 
    ...: x = arange(5) 
    ...: s0 = sin(x[:,None]-x) 
    ...: s1 = sin(x[:,None]) * cos(x) 
    ...: s1 -= s1.T 
    ...: allclose(s0,s1)                                                                  
Out[42]: True
```

Comment: My answer is clearly and heavily influenced by [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60140396/2749397) given above by [Paul Panzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7207392/paul-panzer). I have posted it in the  hope that it has a somehow different charm.